# Saving NSDictionary in NSUserDefaults - hash fails

Tags: ios, objective-c, hash, nsdictionary, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to save a *NSDictionary* to *NSUserDefaults*, and am using MD5 hash to check for integrity, using this helpder class: [Secure-NSUserDefaults](https://github.com/matthiasplappert/Secure-NSUserDefaults).

The code to set the Dictionary:

```
#import "NSUserDefaults+MPSecureUserDefaults.h"

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setSecureObject:aDictionary forKey:aKey];
[defaults synchronize];
```

The code to retrieve it:

```
BOOL valid = NO;
NSDictionary * aDictionary = [defaults secureDictionaryForKey:aKey valid:&valid];
if (!valid) {
  //... hash doesn't match
} else {
  //... hash matches
}
```

This works great as long as the app is running (testing in the simulator right now), but when I exit the simulator and restart the app, the hash value is different than before.

It's as if exiting the app changes the dictionary value (when it's saved to disk perhaps?) in some way. It's not adding visible characters, though, because it looks exactly the same in the debugger.

Would appreciate any ideas from more experienced programmers!

**EDIT:**

So this seems to work for me. Thoughts?

Change NSUserDefaults+MPSecureUserDefaults.m like so:

```
- (NSString *)_hashObject:(id)object
{
   if (_secretData == nil) {
      // Use if statement in case asserts are disabled
      NSAssert(NO, @"Provide a secret before using any secure writing or reading methods!");
      return nil;
   }

   // Copy object to make sure it is immutable (thanks Stephen)
   object = [object copy];

   //added check for array or dictionary
   if ([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:object]) {
      NSMutableData *archivedData = [[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:object options:0 error:nil] mutableCopy];
      [archivedData appendData:_secretData];
      if (_deviceIdentifierData != nil) {
        [archivedData appendData:_deviceIdentifierData];
      }
      NSString *hash = [self _hashData:archivedData];
      return hash;
   }

   // Archive & hash
   NSMutableData *archivedData = [[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:object] mutableCopy];
   [archivedData appendData:_secretData];
   if (_deviceIdentifierData != nil) {
      [archivedData appendData:_deviceIdentifierData];
   }
   NSString *hash = [self _hashData:archivedData];
   ////[archivedData release];
   return hash;
}
```

Comment: You have a slight logic error, should be 
if (valid) { 
and not 
if (!valid) {

Answer (score 0):

The code you are using, Secure-NSUserDefaults, is incorrect.

The code makes assumption about `NSKeyedArchiver`'s `archivedDataWithRootObject:` which are invalid - namely that if two dictionaries are the same then the archived version of them is the same. The internal ordering of key/value pairs in a dictionary is not defined, two dictionaries can be *semantically* the same while being *structurally* different - and if they are structurally different their archived version of them may be also.

Either write your own or fix the library you have used. You need to deal with dictionaries as an ordered collection of key/values pairs - say by sorting based on the key as `NSLog` does when printing them.

HTH

**Addendum: After question edit**

`NSJSONSerialization` suffers from the same problem (for this usage) as `NSKeyedArchiver`, as the simple test I posted on GitHub will show.

It seems you may be missing the core problem here. A dictionary is an *unordered* collection of key/value pairs. The code you are using is attempting to generate a sequence of bytes which is identical (or at least produces the same hash value) for different dictionaries which contain the same key/value pairs *in any order*. The issue is compounded as dictionaries/arrays can contain other arrays/dictionaries to any nesting depth.

The obvious way to do generate a byte sequence independent of the (internal) ordering is to *order* the key/values pairs when producing the byte sequence. However dictionary keys are not required to have an ordering, only an equality, relation.

As there is no ordering requirement on keys the `NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSJSONSerialization` cannot assume one exists and so do not guarantee to produce the same byte sequence for dictionaries with the same key/value pairs which are ordered (internally to the type) differently. Furthermore `NSKeyedArchiver` is preserving the *object graph*, including any sharing, see [Object Graphs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Archiving/Articles/objectgraphs.html), which could also contribute to the differences you observe.

However you are writing property lists and for a dictionary to be valid for inclusion in a property list the keys must be strings (see Apple's [About Property Lists](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists.html)). Now strings  do have an ordering, e.g. `NSString`'s `compare:` method, so in this particular case you can order the key/value pairs. So you can either write your own code, or find pre-written code, which produces a byte stream for *property list* types and orders the dictionary key/value pairs while doing so; then you can use this code in the library you are trying to adopt.

Comment: Thanks for the response! In my test, the dictionary contains merely one key/value pair, however, so there can't be much difference structurally, or can it?

Comment: @user1459524 - It doesn't matter, the code makes an assumption which is wrong. I've tested with one element and it fails as well. You need to come up with an algorithm which returns the same value if two objects are semantically equal (and the `hash` method, while correct, is too imprecise for your needs - too many dictionaries have the same hash). Don't forget the dictionaries/arrays can contain other dictionaries/arrays, so your algorithm has to handle this.

Comment: thanks for the info! It all makes sense. I guess the main problem is that I am a newb and need help from this class to (don't laugh!) even do simple MD5 hashes right for strings and the like (and, for the record, it works well), so coming up with an algorithm to fix the code is outside of my skill set. :)

Comment: So, in order to fix the class, instead of using NSKeyedArchiver, how about using NSJSONSerialization?

Comment: @user1459524 - You will have to determine whether it is suitable. Does it provide the guarantees that are required? I added a simple test case to the issues on `Secure-NSUserDefaults`'s GitHub showing why their code fails, you could use that as a starting point for your testing. But remember, you can only rely on what is guaranteed by the documentation - it may well be that `Secure-NSUserDefaults` used to work when it was originally written - so simple tests can tell you quickly if it doesn't work, but not that it does.

Comment: thanks for the reply! I've added the code I came up with as an answer here and in the GitHub repo. I'm going to try your test code soon, so far it's working in my implementation.

Comment: @user1459524 - What *guarantees* does the `NSJSONSerialisation` documentation give about the format? As mentioned above, it might be that `Secure-NSUserDefaults` originally just happened to work, therefore "so far it's working" won't do. You need to *know* that semantically equivalent dictionaries produce the same result as the rest of the code is based on that, and if you cannot find a guarantee of that you need to write your own code. SO Note: It is better to add your code as an addendum/edit to your question as it is still a question (you can delete the answer afterwards).

Comment: @user1459524 - No report back from your test. I've added an addendum to explain the problem more. HTH.

Comment: Thanks for the addendum. I do understand the problem about unordered dictionaries. What I don't understand is how a dictionary with just one key/value pair can produce a different hash using NDKeyedArchiver after saving it to NSUserDefaults and restarting the app, while NSJSONSerialization seems to work correctly. The test you posted (I didn't yet have time to try it) assumes different ordering of more than 1 element, but the problem I ran into appears with just 1 already. Hopefully I'll have time today to try this more.

Comment: So I've run the test you posted on GitHub, changed it to use NSJSON Serialization and it fails as well. However, when I change the NSDictionary to use only one key/value pair, then BOTH the NSKeyedArchiver and NSJSONSerialization methods return YES. So it seems like something else is at work here entirely that seems to be related to how NSUserDefaults work. As for ordering the elements, I have switched over to using an NSArray (which contains a couple of other arrays). NSArrays are ordered, but I am seeing the same problem I described at the beginning when using NSKeyedArchiver (but not JSON)

Comment: @user1459524 - It can fail with one element as well. NSKeyedArchiver, NSJSONSerialization and NSUserDefaults all do something they can reverse - what goes in and what comes out are semantically the same. None give a guarantee that the intermediate forms they use are the same for inputs which are semantically the same. NSKeyedArchiver also archives the *graph* of objects, which is at least part of the reason you see the failures you do, see [Object Graphs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Archiving/Articles/objectgraphs.html).

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea how this class may be fixed:

`NSDictionary` should be archived with `NSKeyedArchiver` not only to calculate hash over it, but also to be saved like that (archived) in the `NSUserDefaults` (in opposite to the direct storing as it is done now).

In the get method, upon the hash validation, it will be needed additionally to unarchive it with `NSKeyedUnarchiver` to get back original value.

Thanks.